# In C and C++, can I use macros definitions containing space?

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am wondering if macro definitions can contain space. Let's take for example this code:

```
#define MACRO_PARAM int param2

int function(int param1, MACRO_PARAM)
{
    return param1+param2;
}
```

This works ok with Visual Studio 8 and gcc 3.4.5 (mingw). For me this is good enough for the moment but is this standard? or can I rely on this behavior across different compilers?

Thanks,

Iulian

PS: To answer to the question `why would you wanna do that?`: I'm using bison flex for a project and I'm trying to make something reentrant (I need to declare some macros for function parameters).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to end each line of the definition with a \ (except the last).

Comment: In my case the definition has only 1 line I believe it is ok.

Comment: I will select this answer because it provides additional info. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can certainly have multi word (indeed, multi-line) expansions to preprocessor macros, in any remotely-conformant compiler.  C macros are pretty nasty, but if they couldn't even do that, they'd be largely useless.

The preprocessor syntax can do quite a lot (enough that it's easily abused).  See section 6.10.3 of the standard, ISO-9899 ([PDF](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)), if you want or need legalistic chapter and verse.

Comment: +1 @Norman Gray: Thanks! I now see it clearly what do you mean by abuse :) - I'm diving into the bison generated code. Didn't have any problems with flex as it worked quite well without doing much voodoo. But with bison I believe I unleashed the evil god of macros.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Is this part of the (standard) documentation?

Comment: @Iulian: A space is a very common character. I don't know if the C and the C++ standards explicitly say that "preprocessor macros can contain spaces", but that would be a bit like saying "function names can contain the letter 'z'".

Comment: +1 I believe it is a good way of thinking (what's not explicitly forbidden is allowed :) )

Comment: @Iulian: According to standard 2.4/2 (lex.pptoken), "Preprocessing tokens can be separated by white space; this consists of comments, or white-space characters". So space is okay in macro replacement-list.

Comment: @czchen: Great clarification. Are you quoting the C or the C++ standard?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rely on this behaviour.